# Three20: TTTableControlItem caption's width

Tags: ios, three20

I have a simple login form on a TTTableView, in which I use TTTableControlItem with UITextFields.

I have two fields, Email & Password. Since the UILabel's width determined by the text, the two textfields aren't aligned vertically to the same line and it looks bad.

[image: TTTableControlItem captions width]

How do I control the width of the caption inside?
Is there another way to achieve this without subclassing/finding the labels/controls and move them after render?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass `TTTableControlCell` with your own custom cell and override the function

```
- (void)layoutSubviews;
```

to layout the contents the way you want to.

Also don't forget to map `TTTableControlItem` to your new custom cell subclass in your data source (in the

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id) object;
```

method)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I chose to just set the text field to align the text on the right.  I didn't like the amount of padding so I modified TTTableControlCell to cut back the width of the text field.